# Area of triangle given vertices

Tags: calculus

Find the area of a triangle with the vertices $A(x,0,0),B(x,2x,3x),C(0,x,2x)$.

I have not seen such a problem before. I have a thought that the points given are actually
$(1,0,0),(1,2,3), and (0,1,2)$.
I am not sure though. Is this on the right track?

Comment: You are not told that $x=1$, and so your approach does not work. Note that the area of triangle will be expressed in terms of $x$. Why don't you try plotting $A$, $B$, and $C$ on a coordinate plane, and then applying a formula for the area of a triangle?

Comment: Since the coordinates are homogeneous in $x$ (all nonzero terms have the same degree), you _can_ start with $x=1$ and then take an extra step to cover all $x$. Can you figure out that second step?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the formula
$$
A=\frac{1}{2}ab|\sin{C}|\\
=\frac{1}{2}|\vec{AC}||\vec{BC}|\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{\vec{AC}\cdot\vec{BC}}{|\vec{AC}||\vec{BC}|}\right)^2}
=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{|\vec{AC}|^2|\vec{BC}|^2-(\vec{AC}\cdot\vec{BC})^2}
=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{18x^4-4x^4}
=\frac{\sqrt{14}}{2}x^2
$$